# Janrain and Disqus integration with Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, disqus, janrain

I am developing a BlackBerry application for the Storm, running OS 5.0. Things were all going well until the requirement came to share items via twitter, facebook, mail, janrain and disqus. I managed to integrate twitter, facebook and mail. Now I need to integrate janrain and disqus.

I searched and found that sdk's are provided only for iPhone and Android. Please let me know where I can find out some documentations or reference for this.

Comment: What is it you want to do with janrain and disqus?  Perhaps there is a web API that will work instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.  I want to share some details from within the application Im developing in blackberry using janrain and disqus. I've successfully integrated disqus now. But for Janrain integration I'm not able to get any blackberry support. From the Janrain forums, I got info that, they are not providing bb support. So how can I manage to call their api's programatically. Is their any documentation or useful links, please share.

Comment: can you guide me on how to integrate disqus in blackberry.I have loaded the html page on browserfield  but on when i tap on facebook,twitter nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Disqus integration, either you have to have a site with disqus integrated and create threads and do posts or create an app inside disqus, then using api's create thread and make posts there.

For Janrain, got a third party android lib source. Using that we got the url's to which the API calls should be made.